# Authentication component options for large .NET websites

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership

What do large websites built in .NET use for their login components?

I will be implementing the login and membership features of a large .NET web application.  As I see it, there are 4 options:

1. Leverage the default Microsoft Membership Provider
2. Build a custom Membership Provider
3. Use a different 3rd Party Component
4. Build an entirely custom login/authentication framework

I am trying to optimize for reliability, so I would like to know if sites like MySpace or PlentyOfFish have already established a best practice in this area.  The real motivation for this question is I want to validate that the MS Membership Provider strategy will scale well.

I know StackOverflow uses OpenID, but I don't think that would be a good solution for what I am working on as a lot of my prospective users will be non-technical.  Feel free to pitch why OpenID should be considered if you believe strongly in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Always*** rely as much as possible on platform-provided tools for security tasks such as authentication.

In this case, that likely means *inheriting* from one of the stock MembershipProviders.  That will let you re-use all the existing code for the provider, plus any tweaks you need to make it work with your existing system.  It's possible you can find a 3rd party component that works well for you that already does this.